# PhpStorm 9 Darcula theme is not completely black

Tags: phpstorm

As I said and following figure illustrates PhpStorm 9 Darcula theme is not completely black, How can I achieve full black PhpStorm like preceding versions?

[image: PhpStorm 9 Darcula Theme]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have changed the GUI Theme to be Darcula but forgot to change Editor Scheme to a dark one (Darcula or any other).

**Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Colors & Fonts --> Scheme**

**P.S.**

The correct name of dark theme is D**ar**cula and not D**ra**cula.